# Is there an option to edit the padding inside of a Tkinter EntryBox?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there an option to edit the padding inside of a Tkinter EntryBox? So that the text that the user inputs starts e.g. 10px from the left border.

Comment: I don't believe there is. You can however use the `justify` parameter to justify your text left, right, or centered.

Comment: Too bad :/ But justify does the job too, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Technically, yes if you are using `.grid()`.

Using:

```
grid(ipadx=HORIZONTAL-PADDING, ipady=VERTICAL-PADDING)
```

Is what the documentation says, however it doesn't seem to dictate how the text bbehaves. I can only get it to work for `ipady`. `ipadx` seems to just add extra padding to extend the width of the Entry widget without the text moving right.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0,ipadx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Reference:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm